# How to configure watermarks in coverage reports when using jest?

Tags: testing, jestjs, istanbul, test-coverage

My coverage report runs fine, but I would like to configure the watermarks that is used to mark coverage green, yellow and red.

My coverage report currently look like this:
[image]

It seems RED is used when coverage is < **50** and GREEN is used when coverage is > **80** and else YELLOW is used.

**Where can I configure these values, so I can use e.g. 40 and 60 instead?**

My own research on this ended here: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#coveragereporters-arraystring--string-options
and here: https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc/blob/master/README.md#installation--usage

It seems that something like this should be used:

```
{
  "watermarks": {
    "lines": [40, 70],
    "functions": [40, 70],
    "branches": [40, 70],
    "statements": [40, 70]
  }
}
```

But where should I put it? I have tried to put in a file called .nycrc and in package.json. It did not work.

I use Jest for testing ("jest --coverage") - in VSCode and I use NPM/NESTJS.

Comment: This is still bugging me. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

This does not appear to be possible in Jest.

The watermark config is for istanbul which is built in to Jest.  Furthermore, the istanbul project states that its configuration is handled directly through Jest. https://istanbul.js.org/docs/tutorials/jest/. You should be able to set the istanbul config using the `--coverage` flag.

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work for setting the watermark thresholds in `jest`. [This issue was raised](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/9734) in the `jest` project, but it became stale and was closed with no action taken.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to set this in your Jest config:

```
"coverageThreshold": {
  "global": {
    "branches": 70,
    "functions": 70,
    "lines": 70,
    "statements": 70
  }
},
```

These will get mapped by jest onto the istanbul settings as `[default_from_istanbul, your_number]` per category. It means that your number will become threshold for yellow watermark and red watermark will stay exactly how the default is in istambul (currently 50%).

This setting will also cause your tests to fail if run with coverage. That being said, I'd prefer it was mapped onto a red watermark but it is what it is ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Be aware that this works only for "global", you cannot set it per-file or per-glob (it's actually a limitation of istambul reporters).

Answer (score -1):

It's been so long that I'm sure you already found the answer, @Mikael. Posting it here, just in case someone else needs it ...

Starting [here in the jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#collectcoverage-boolean), you'll see all the config options for code coverage.

Here's an example that I'm using on my project, saved to a file named `jest.config.js`.

```js
module.exports = {
  passWithNoTests: true,

  // collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    './docs/**/*.{js,jsx}',
    '!**/media/**',
    '!**/node_modules/**',
    '!**/vendor/**',
    '!**/_site/**',
  ],
  coverageDirectory: "./coverage/",
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      branches: 80,
      functions: 80,
      lines: 80,
      statements: -10,
    },
  },
};
```

And my `package.json` has the following scripts (among others):

```json
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "test-coverage": "npm run test -- --coverage",
    "test-watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "test-watch-all": "npm run test -- --watchAll",
  },
  ...
```

Comment: Does not answer the issue about watermarks.